# How to give new line in a TextBox in WinUi3

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

I have a problem in adding in a new line in a TextBox in WinUi3.

I am getting the following data as input:

```
WEATHERCHECK/It's raining heavily/Start of play delayed for 2 hours 43 mins
```

For every '/', its supposed to go to a new Line, but not happening.

- I first replaced '/' with '\n', didnt work
- Then replaced '/' with '\r\n', didnt work
- Then split the text with '/' & added '\r\n' - didnt work

```
  string[] values = value.Split("/");

  foreach(string value1 in values)
  {
      Commentary.Text += value1 + "\r\n";
  }
```

- Used Environment.NewLine - didnt work

```
  string[] values = value.Split("/");
string newLine = Environment.NewLine;

  foreach(string value1 in values)
  {
      Commentary.Text += value1 + newLine;
  }
```

Result is still same:
[image]

XAML for Textbox

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <TextBox Height="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="500" x:Name="Commentary" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Red" Background="AliceBlue" Text="Commentary" />
 </StackPanel>
```

What can I do to show each part in new Line ?

**Solved:**

As per Comment from Luuk, I gave AcceptsReturn = "true" in XAML and used the same loop to add "\r\n" at the end and it worked.

Comment: Setting [AcceptsRetrun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptsreturn?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to true should o that ?  (quote: "true if pressing the ENTER key inserts a new line at the current cursor position; **otherwise, the ENTER key is ignored.**" )

Comment: Oh yes, it did it, I didnt use it because I thought thats applicable only on manual text input and we press Enter. Many thanks

Comment: @Luuk Could you please post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting [AcceptsRetrun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptsreturn?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to true should o that ? (quote: "true if pressing the ENTER key inserts a new line at the current cursor position; otherwise, the ENTER key is ignored." )